# Trying to deploy flask app on Heroku, deployment works fine until I add sessions in my code, then it's giving 500 internal error. how to resolve this?

Tags: python, flask, heroku, web-applications, web-deployment

**Piece of Code**

```
def wishListCount():
wishlist_count = len(session['Wishlist'])
if len(session['Wishlist']) <= 0:
    return 0    
else:
    return wishlist_count

@app.route('/wishlist', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'])
def wishlist():
if request.method == 'POST':
    product_id = int(request.form['product_id'])
    ListItems = [product_id]
    if 'Wishlist' in session:
        if product_id in session['Wishlist']:
            print("This product is already in wishList!")
        else:
            session['Wishlist'] = mergeDict(session['Wishlist'], ListItems)
    else:
        session['Wishlist'] = ListItems
wishlist_count = wishListCount()
```

**Heroku logs**

State changed from starting to up

2020-05-07T00:37:33.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded

2020-05-07T00:37:39.445026+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=intelli-supermart.herokuapp.com request_id=bc70627f-fbff-4722-8b7e-f97c18e7e2d5 fwd="203.128.16.105" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=102ms status=500 bytes=470 protocol=https

2020-05-07T00:37:39.441994+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-07 00:37:39,440] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]

2020-05-07T00:37:39.442004+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):

2020-05-07T00:37:39.442005+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app

2020-05-07T00:37:39.442005+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self.full_dispatch_request()

2020-05-07T00:37:39.442006+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request

2020-05-07T00:37:39.442006+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

2020-05-07T00:37:39.442007+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception

2020-05-07T00:37:39.442007+00:00 app[web.1]: reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

2020-05-07T00:37:39.442007+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise

2020-05-07T00:37:39.442008+00:00 app[web.1]: raise value

2020-05-07T00:37:39.442009+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request

2020-05-07T00:37:39.442009+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.dispatch_request()

2020-05-07T00:37:39.442009+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request

2020-05-07T00:37:39.442010+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint

2020-05-07T00:37:39.442010+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 117, in index

2020-05-07T00:37:39.442011+00:00 app[web.1]: wishlist_count = wishListCount()

2020-05-07T00:37:39.442011+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 79, in wishListCount

2020-05-07T00:37:39.442011+00:00 app[web.1]: wishlist_count = len(session['Wishlist'])

2020-05-07T00:37:39.442012+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 377, in

2020-05-07T00:37:39.442012+00:00 app[web.1]: **getitem** = lambda x, i: x._get_current_object()[i]

2020-05-07T00:37:39.442012+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 84, in **getitem**

2020-05-07T00:37:39.442013+00:00 app[web.1]: return super(SecureCookieSession, self).**getitem**(key)

2020-05-07T00:37:39.442019+00:00 app[web.1]: KeyError: 'Wishlist'

2020-05-07T00:37:39.445086+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.11.150.203 - - [07/May/2020:00:37:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the key `WishList` in not in the `session` variable. Always you doulf check if the key in in the session by using this

```
if 'WishList' in session:
```

Also you should assign something to `session['WishList']` at the beginning of the code

Comment: What should I assign to a session at the beginning which will have no effect when I try to extract my data from the session?

Comment: I didn't add this `if 'WishList' in session:` condition in my **wishListCount():** function. After adding it now it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That seems like you don't have `Wishlist` in your session. You can try getting the variable by using `session.get('Wishlist')` and will return `None` if there's no Wishlist in the session. Hope this will help.

Comment: oh yes, thanks I simply added `if 'WishList' in session:` at start of my **wishListCount():** function, and the issue is resolved.